# Merge two PHP Script to works together

Tags: php

I have Data entry form where user insert there data along with upload three category image file .In present situation Data insert and image upload is working fine but works separately for example its appear echo"insert successfully" for both data & image insertion.I want it works  together . Here i present my script :

```
enter code here

        <?php


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {



    $date=$_POST["date"];
    $agentid=$_POST["agentid"];
    $formno=$_POST["formno"];
    $bank=$_POST["bank"];
    $ptype=$_POST["ptype"];
    $cardno=$_POST["cardno"];
    $cname=$_POST["cname"];
    $fname=$_POST["fname"];
    $mname=$_POST["mname"];
    $dob=$_POST["dob"];
    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
    $votarid=$_POST["votarid"];
    $sex=$_POST["sex"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $district=$_POST["district"];
    $thana=$_POST["thana"];


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","myapps");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $sql= "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
       `cardno`,`cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
       `email`, `district`, `thana`)
       VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
        '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //check for errors

    $sql="UPDATE card SET status='1',agentid='$agentid',salesdate='$date' WHERE 
    $cardno=cardno";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    echo "One raw Successfully inserted";
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
    <?php

    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
        $res =  upload_multiple_file($_FILES['files'],"KYCFILE",$formno);
        //echo $res;
        }


    function upload_multiple_file($file,$file_dir="KYCFILE",$formno=null) {

        $overwrite=0;
        $allowed_file_type= array("JPG","jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
        $max_file_size = 2097152;
        $max_file_size_check=0;
         foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $fkey=> $fname){

             $ext = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
               if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_file_type)) {

                   return "unsupported file format";
                    break;
               }


         }

        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){


            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];


            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];


            $file_tmp_name =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];


            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];


            //if($max_file_size_check >0) {
                if($file_size > $max_file_size){

                    $fsize=$max_file_size/1048576;
                    return  'File size must be less than '.$fsize.' MB';
                    break;

                }
            //}


            if(is_dir($file_dir)==false){

                  $status =  mkdir("$file_dir", 0700);  

                   if($status < 1){

                         return "unable to create  diractory $file_dir ";

                    }              

            }
            $new_file_path=$file_dir."/".$formno;
            if(is_dir($new_file_path)==false){

                  $status =  mkdir("$new_file_path", 0700); 

                   if($status < 1){

                         return "unable to create  diractory $file_dir ";

                    }              

            }

            if(is_dir($new_file_path)){
                /*switch($key)
                    $file_name="photo".str_split(""
                case:0*/
                echo $file_name;
                $splitted_filename=explode(".",$file_name);
                $file_ext=$splitted_filename[1];
                switch($key) {
                    case 0:
                        $file_name_new="photo.".$file_ext;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $file_name_new="voter_id.".$file_ext;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $file_name_new="KYC_form.".$file_ext;
                        break;
                }
                if($overwrite < 1){


      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"$new_file_path/".$formno."_".$file_name_new);

                }

            }

            //  $file_upload_query="INSERT into user_uploads 
      (`u_id`,`file_name`,`file_type`)  
      VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
            //mysql_query($file_upload_query);      


       }

            return "One raw Successfully inserted";
            header("refresh:2;url=kycapps.php" );

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please, learn how to use [prepared statements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY). Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {



$date=$_POST["date"];
$agentid=$_POST["agentid"];
$formno=$_POST["formno"];
$bank=$_POST["bank"];
$ptype=$_POST["ptype"];
$cardno=$_POST["cardno"];
$cname=$_POST["cname"];
$fname=$_POST["fname"];
$mname=$_POST["mname"];
$dob=$_POST["dob"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$votarid=$_POST["votarid"];
$sex=$_POST["sex"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$district=$_POST["district"];
$thana=$_POST["thana"];


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","myapps");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql= "INSERT INTO `kyc`( `date`,`agentid`,`formno`, `bank`, `ptype`,
   `cardno`,`cname`, `fname`, `mname`, `dob`, `phone`, `votarid`,`sex`, 
   `email`, `district`, `thana`)
   VALUES('$date','$agentid',$formno,'$bank','$ptype','$cardno','$cname','$fname',
    '$mname','$dob',$phone,$votarid,'$sex','$email','$district','$thana')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //check for errors

$sql="UPDATE card SET status='1',agentid='$agentid',salesdate='$date' WHERE 
$cardno=cardno";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $res =  upload_multiple_file($_FILES['files'],"KYCFILE",$formno);
    //echo $res;
 }


echo "One raw Successfully inserted";
mysqli_close($con);
 header("refresh:2;url=kycapps.php" );
}


function upload_multiple_file($file,$file_dir="KYCFILE",$formno=null) {

    $overwrite=0;
    $allowed_file_type= array("JPG","jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
    $max_file_size = 2097152;
    $max_file_size_check=0;
     foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $fkey=> $fname){

         $ext = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_file_type)) {

               return "unsupported file format";
                break;
           }


     }

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){


        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];


        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];


        $file_tmp_name =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];


        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];


        //if($max_file_size_check >0) {
            if($file_size > $max_file_size){

                $fsize=$max_file_size/1048576;
                return  'File size must be less than '.$fsize.' MB';
                break;

            }
        //}


        if(is_dir($file_dir)==false){

              $status =  mkdir("$file_dir", 0700);  

               if($status < 1){

                     return "unable to create  diractory $file_dir ";

                }              

        }
        $new_file_path=$file_dir."/".$formno;
        if(is_dir($new_file_path)==false){

              $status =  mkdir("$new_file_path", 0700); 

               if($status < 1){

                     return "unable to create  diractory $file_dir ";

                }              

        }

        if(is_dir($new_file_path)){
            /*switch($key)
                $file_name="photo".str_split(""
            case:0*/
            echo $file_name;
            $splitted_filename=explode(".",$file_name);
            $file_ext=$splitted_filename[1];
            switch($key) {
                case 0:
                    $file_name_new="photo.".$file_ext;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $file_name_new="voter_id.".$file_ext;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $file_name_new="KYC_form.".$file_ext;
                    break;
            }
            if($overwrite < 1){


  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"$new_file_path/".$formno."_".$file_name_new);

            }

        }

        //  $file_upload_query="INSERT into user_uploads 
  (`u_id`,`file_name`,`file_type`)  
  VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        //mysql_query($file_upload_query);      


   }


}
```